# Can you have multiple connected isolated networks in qemu?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, virtual-machine, qemu

I wanted to emulate a cybersecurity attack using multiple different VMs on qemu and usually they have IP Addresses that can be very different (for example, usually the attack machine is 192.168.0.x and the target machines are usually at 10.0.2.x), and I understand that emulating that is not possible on just one network (as far as I know the Network address defines the range of the start and end for the DHCP server and hence I'm unable to assign such different IP Addresses on just one network), so I wanted to ask, would it be possible to create 2 networks and then have them access each other on qemu? Will I need a router that connects both the Networks?

Comment: Are you using qemu via libvirt or directly?

Comment: I'm using qemu via libvirt yes, since I use virt-manager

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple ip ranges is normally not prohibited on the network. The router, if its acting as dhcp will only dole out a single range of addresses. But you can nominate any fixed ipaddress for your device.

Whether the source machine can talk to the target depends on the targets firewall.

I often use a separate subrange for a new device that I dont want others to access, just yet.  Similarly, if I  am on a VPN, I  have 2 ipaddresses.

If required, a windows PC can have multiple ipaddresses, so it should be possible on other platforms and vms too.